# Iptables with dynamic ip list

Tags: iptables

We have 5 servers in EU datacenter and 5 servers in US datacenter. All servers have some Redis instances installed and Redis port is opened for IP adresses from list (via `iptables`). All Redis's instances from all servers are communicating with each other.

Adding new server is real pain because I should grant access to Redis port on all servers for new IP address.

Is there any way to avoid doing this routine? First and simple approach is to fetch some list of ip addresses and refresh `iptables` rules according to this list. Or maybe there is more elegant solution?

Comment: What configuration management tools do you use?

Comment: @lain, it's a pity, but absolutely no configuration management tools. Only manual setup. Is there any configuration management system with low entrance level that you can recommend. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just my little idea:

Create an ipset, make the rules you need in iptables with maching the set, then just update the set to add a new ip, without needing to touch again the iptables rules. This last step could easily be automated by a script, but it is quick and fast to do by hand, too. (I use this to download and filter list of bad ips).

`ipset -N myiplist chooseYourType`

`-A INPUT -m set --match-set myipslist src -j ACCEPT`

`ipset add myipslist 1.2.3.4`

And do not forget that the ipsets are like iptables rules, they need to be reloaded after a restart of the server.

Answer (score 1):

This just screams like a job for Chef or Puppet to take care of. Here is the puppet library for it: https://forge.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs/firewall Here is the Chef one: https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/iptables

Once you get into a tool like Chef or Puppet, you will find lots of other things to automate with it as well. So if you do not have such tools today it is VERY much worth your time and effort to get one going and standardize your configurations, deployments, patching, etc. It does take a little bit of time, but like I said, it is well worth it in the long run.

Comment: I definitely should try Puppet.